# Searching for tweets by date using Twitterapiexchange

Tags: php, twitter

I am attempting to search tweets within a given date range, using the twitterapiexchange wrapper.

Here is my code

```
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');
$settings = array(
'oauth_access_token' => "xx",
'oauth_access_token_secret' => "xx",
'consumer_key' => "xx",
'consumer_secret' => "xx"
);

$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json";

$requestMethod = "GET"

$getfield = "?q=from:manutd&until:2018-01-20&since:2018-01-01";
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);
if(array_key_exists("errors", $string)) {echo "<h3>Sorry, there was a problem.</h3> 
  <p>Twitter returned the following error message:</p><p><em>".$string[errors][0] 
  ["message"]."</em></p>";exit();}
  foreach($string as $items)
  {


    echo "Time and Date of Tweet: ".$items['created_at']."<br />";
    echo "Tweet: ". $items['full_text']."<br />";
    echo "Tweeted by: ". $items['user']['name']."<br />";
    echo "Screen name: ". $items['user']['screen_name']."<br />";
    echo "Followers: ". $items['user']['followers_count']."<br />";
    echo "Friends: ". $items['user']['friends_count']."<br />";
    echo "Listed: ". $items['user']['listed_count']."<br /><hr />";



   }
```

This returns the latest tweets from the specified user, the date field appears to be ignored.

Is it possible to search by date using the API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search API supports this, but you have to assemble your query like so:

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=from%3Atwitterdev&result_type=mixed&count=2

Refer: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets

The query string above is the urlencoded form of:

so you will pass like

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%3Afrom:manutd&until:2018-01-20&since:2018-01-01
```

The list of search operators can be found [here](http://search.twitter.com/operators).